# awk -- duplicating a column and also modifying its text

Tags: text-processing, awk

```
awk {'printf ("%5s\t%s\n", $0, $NF)'} test_VN.txt
```

works for duplicating a column in a text file however, how can I add `_VN` before the `.jpeg` extension of the duplicated column?

For example, I want to have this output:

```
21_48.jpeg  21_48_VN.jpeg
24_48.jpeg  24_48_VN.jpeg
25_48.jpeg  25_48_VN.jpeg
```

I want to read the first column from test_VN.txt which only has one column and save it to test_VN_2.txt with two columns.

*Yes, my intention was tab separation between two columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
gsub(/\.jpeg/, "_VN.jpeg", <your string>)
```

for substring replacement.
So you want

```
awk '{ f=$1 ; gsub(/\.jpeg/, "_VN.jpeg", f) ; printf ("%5s\t%s\n", $1, f) }' test_VN.txt > test_VN_2.txt
```

You might have used `sub` as well.

Comment: awesome! this is stellar!

Comment: `sub` would be sufficient here I think (since only a single replacement per string is required)

Comment: @steeldriver - Right. I am simply used to `gsub` (and so I ab-used of it).